# 301 redirects keep going to page not found

Tags: http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I am currently working on a website. I was not the developer  but i am doing the fixes. The plugin simple 301 redirect is being used to redirect the dead site pages to the new live site. The issue is that even tho the url's for the old site is correct and so are the new ones, some of the old url's redirect properly but others are going to page not found. Any advise?

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: Please elaborate in more detail what you have already tried, what you are struggling with. What are the server response headers of the pages that redirect correctly, how do they look when they redirect to a 404? Maybe the URLs redirected to are just wrong, hence the 404?